# Returning a value from a function which requires an asynchronous call first

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Our payment gateway provides an embedded widget that we can use on our payment page. They have a javascript event that fires as the person clicks the "Pay now" button where we are able to run some javascript code before the card gets submitted to the payment gateway. If we return true from this function then the card data will be submitted, but if we return false then the card data will not be submitted.

We are wanting to make a AJAX call to our server when the buyer clicks "Pay now" and alter some information on the purchase before proceeding to submit the payment data to the payment gateway. However this call is asynchronous so returning true after a successful call does not work.

Here is the code we use. wpwlOptions is used by the payment gateways payment script. We are using Angular. onBeforeSubmitCard is where the issue is and we don't have any way of altering how the payment gateway handles it, all it wants is a true or false.

```
window.wpwlOptions = {
            style: "plain",
            onReady: function() {
                $scope.checkouted=true;
                $scope.$apply();
            },
            onBeforeSubmitCard: function () {                  
                paymentService.extendCheckout(checkoutData).then(function (response) {

                    if (response.extendedUntil) {
                        console.log(response);
                        return true;
                    }
                    else {
                        tpBootstrapUtilities.showErrorPopup({ message: 'An error occurred, please contact support@ticketpony.co.za' });
                        return false;
                    }
                }, function () {
                    $scope.failed = true;
                    tpBootstrapUtilities.showErrorPopup({ message: 'An error occurred, please contact support@ticketpony.co.za' });
                    return false;
                });

            }
        };
```

Then the extendCheckout from the paymentService is below:

```
extendCheckout: function (data) {
            var deferred = $q.defer();
            $http({
                url: ENVIRONMENT_CONSTANTS.SERVICES_URI + SYSTEM_CONSTANTS.SERVICES.PAYMENT + '/extend',
                method: 'POST',
                data: data
            }).success(function (response) {
                deferred.resolve(response);
            }).error(function (response) {
                deferred.reject(response);
            });
            return deferred.promise;
        },
```

Thanks

Comment: So what is the problem, just work with promises api you already have something.

Comment: Why can you not simply wire up your ajax function to the button, and then on success call the paymentService there?

Comment: dfsq I don't think they can return a promise because the API they are using explicitly wants true or false.

Comment: @dfsq the payment gateway wants a true or false, so I cannot return a promise to them.

Comment: @Sinistralis the payment gateway binds events to the click of the button (the button / form is dynamically made by their javascript script).

Comment: Is it feasible to completely hide this widget from view and use a dummy form? Then when the user tries to submit it, perform an ajax request, and on success fill out the actual form with the edited data and then programmatically submit it? It's incredibly ugly, but given your constraints I don't see a much cleaner option. It's a little absurd that they don't accept a promise.

Comment: @Sinistralis I agree, they should accept promises - I would imagine most use cases for this functionality would be to make an AJAX call. It is feasible to hack the form but not something I would want to do. Going to try see if I can make the $http call synchronous instead.

Comment: You can, it is an option in both the original spec and the jQuery implementation. I never used it so I completely forgot about it.